# Heroku rails deploy error on assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, precompile

I got this error when trying to deploy a rails app on heroku

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:112:in `getaddrinfo'
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:112:in `connect'
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:174:in `connect'
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:263:in `establish_connection'
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:69:in `connect'
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:282:in `ensure_connected'
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:173:in `block in process'
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:248:in `logging'
   /tmp/build_3bx0fu8vccj6s/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:172:in `process'
```

Comment: This is not enough information for us to help you. I can only tell that something seems to be wrong with your redis server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable User_env_compile in heroku labs

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile
```

And then redeploy your application. More info at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile